# how can i deal with this problem "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined"

Tags: jquery, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

html file:-

```
<div class="my-3">
<label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
<a class="minus-cart btn"><i class="fas fa-minus-square fa-lg" id="{{cart.product.id}}" ></i></a>
<span id="quantity">{{cart.quantity}}</span>
<a class="plus-cart btn"><i class="fas fa-plus-square fa-lg pid={{cart.product.id}} ></i></a>
</div>
```

jquery file:-

```
$('.plus-cart').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("pid").toString();
    var eml = this.parentNode.children[2];
    console.log(id);
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "/pluscart",
            data: {
                prod_id: id
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                eml.innerText = data.quantity;
                document.getElementById("amount").innerText = data.amount.toFixed(2);
                document.getElementById("totalamount").innerText = data.totalamount.toFixed(2);
            }
        })
});
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qhr0.png)

please help me to solve this probelm this is last error that i have been occure in my project

Answer (score 1):

`pid` is in child element ( `i` ) not in `a` tag

```
$(this).children("i").attr("pid").toString()
```

Or move `pid` to `a` tag

```
<a class="plus-cart btn" pid={{cart.product.id}}><i class="fas fa-plus-square fa-lg></i></a>
```

Comment: but after doing this I can also get errors they cant read the value of cart.product.id but if i display cart.product.id they can show the value but they cant send to ajax so what can i do

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred because the pid is not in the `a` tag.

```
<div class="my-3">
<label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
<a class="minus-cart btn"><i class="fas fa-minus-square fa-lg" id="{{cart.product.id}}"></i></a>
<span id="quantity">{{cart.quantity}}</span>
<a class="plus-cart btn" pid={{cart.product.id}}><i class="fas fa-plus-square fa-lg></i></a>
</div>
```

Please fix it like this.

**Other ways:**

*I think if you send some data using attr, it's not enough for coding style*

You can do it using data attr like this.

`in html`

```
<div class="my-3">
<label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
<a class="minus-cart btn"><i class="fas fa-minus-square fa-lg" id="{{cart.product.id}}"></i></a>
<span id="quantity">{{cart.quantity}}</span>
<a class="plus-cart btn" data-pid={{cart.product.id}}><i class="fas fa-plus-square fa-lg></i></a>
</div>
```

`in jquery`

```
$('.plus-cart').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).data("pid").toString();
    var eml = this.parentNode.children[2];
    console.log(id);
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "/pluscart",
            data: {
                prod_id: id
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                eml.innerText = data.quantity;
                document.getElementById("amount").innerText = data.amount.toFixed(2);
                document.getElementById("totalamount").innerText = data.totalamount.toFixed(2);
            }
        })
});
```

Also I think you don't need to call `.toString()` method.

Comment: can you explain in more details?

Comment: Thank You So much sir from your support i have complete my whole project thank you do much again and again